# Dynamic generation of mysql query

Tags: spring, hibernate, struts

Am generating tables dynamically by entering the table name and field names in text fields.i Am using spring,struts and hibernate framework.the user can generate any number of table rows by clicking the add row button.My problem is how can i write the query for inserting these table rows in database.How can i get the field value of these dynamically generated table rows.If one row only is there means i can simply write a single insert query.But what about multiple rows.

Comment: create a Entity Bean that represents the row of data and save it using hibernate. Try some sample hibernate tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

if you are sing hibernate, your queries (CRUD) is written and handled by Hibernate.. so all you would need to do is to define a pojo and link it to a desired db table (either by using annotations or hibernate mapping files).

once you have the data from the struts2 action and populated in the pojo, you need to say

```
Session s = // get session from sessionFactory

s.save(s);
```

if you have more than 1 element to insert then you can say

```
Session s= // get session from sessionFactory
s.saveOrUpdateAll(collectionOfPojoObjectsWithData);
```